# How to do substraction in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.2

I want to subtracted 23000 with 1000 again and again until its 0.
So i want the result like this

```
1000 |  23000
1000 |  22000
1000 |  21000
1000 |  20000
.
.
.
1000 |  0
```

Can anyone help me how to do it in PostgreSQL? Thanks!

Comment: And what is the input data to this output?

Comment: see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=852a3f7e96be9fcdd5fef6af973dfa56

Comment: I cant do the code that u gave me (with recursive) in my pgAdmin version. Can u provide me with another solution? Thanks

Comment: @niaa: the pgAdmin version is irrelevant for the usage of a recursive CTE. The version of the Postgres server is relevant. But `with recursive` has been supported since Postgres 8.4 (long retired and unsupported). What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: Recursion is needed to generate rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My version is 8.2.15

Comment: Postgres 8.2 has been out of support for over a decade. You shouldn't use it any more. And you should always mention this in the question if you are using completely outdated versions of something. But you still haven't answered the question: what is the *input* data to get that output?

Comment: There is generate_series(23000,0,-1000)

Comment: Are you sure about version 8.2.15? This version was released 2009-12-14. You didn't do any maintenance over the last 12 years? Advice: Migrate to a newer version asap.

Comment: @all what if 23000 and 1000 is a numeric? I cant use generate_series with my postgreSQL other than integer :(

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a series

> ```
> SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(23000 ,0 ,-1000)
> ```
>
> ```
> | generate_series |
> | --------------: |
> |           23000 |
> |           22000 |
> |           21000 |
> |           20000 |
> |           19000 |
> |           18000 |
> |           17000 |
> |           16000 |
> |           15000 |
> |           14000 |
> |           13000 |
> |           12000 |
> |           11000 |
> |           10000 |
> |            9000 |
> |            8000 |
> |            7000 |
> |            6000 |
> |            5000 |
> |            4000 |
> |            3000 |
> |            2000 |
> |            1000 |
> |               0 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8f2306261763f7c983e3ad33aaf06ba9)*

Answer (score 0):

using `while loop`

```
CREATE TABLE test(a int,x int);
do $$
declare
x1 integer := 23000;
begin
while x1 >= 0 loop
insert into test(a,x)
select 1000,x1 ;
x1 :=x1-1000;
end loop;
end$$;

select * from test
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f6b6e996f0d57cd42b4edac4297d8f49)

Comment: There was no `do` command in the outdated version nia is using.